# Java type inference: reference is ambiguous in Java 8, but not Java 7

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, java-8, type-inference

Lets say we have 2 classes. An empty class `Base`, and a subclass of this class `Derived`.

```
public class Base {}

public class Derived extends Base {}
```

Then we have a few methods in another class:

```
import java.util.Collection

public class Consumer {

    public void test() {
        set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());
    }

    public <T extends Base> T get() {
        return (T) new Derived();
    }

    public void set(Base i, Derived b) {
        System.out.println("base");
    }

    public void set(Derived d, Collection<? extends Consumer> o) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }

}
```

This compiles and runs successfully in Java 7, but does not compile in Java 8. The error:

```
Error:(8, 9) java: reference to set is ambiguous
  both method set(Base,Derived) in Consumer and 
  method set(Derived,java.util.Collection) in Consumer match
```

**Why does work in Java 7, but not Java 8? How could `<T extends Base>` *ever* match Collection?**

Comment: Well, it compiles fine for me with Java 8

Comment: Eclipse compiles this, but `javac` cannot. Is it safe to assume you're using `javac`?

Comment: @Jeffrey Yes. I get this error compiling from the commandline with javac, and with IntelliJ. 

I'm using java version 1.8.0_25

Comment: You can have things extending Base implementing Collection...

Comment: This is the same issue as [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799), except that things have been *"improved"* in Java 8 (in fact, the spec is unintuitive, but compilers behave correctly according to the spec)

Comment: @Jeffrey, for the records: Eclipse 4.4 accepted this program (with an "unchecked" warning!), but starting from 4.5M3 also Eclipse reports the ambiguity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The problem is that the type inference has been *improved*. You have a method like

```
public <T extends Base> T get() {
    return (T) new Derived();
}
```

which basically says, “the caller can decide what subclass of `Base` I return”, which is obvious nonsense. Every compiler should give you an unchecked warning about your type cast `(T)` here.

Now you have a method call:

```
set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());
```

Recall that your method `Consumer.get()` says “the caller can decide what I return”. So it’s perfectly correct to assume that there could be a type which extends `Base` and implement `Collection` at the same time. So the compiler says “I don’t know whether to call `set(Base i, Derived b)` or `set(Derived d, Collection<? extends Consumer> o)`”.

You can “fix” it by calling `set(new Derived(), new Consumer().<Derived>get());` but to illustrate the madness of your method, note that you can also change it to

```
public <X extends Base&Collection<Consumer>> void test() {
    set(new Derived(), new Consumer().<X>get());
}
```

which will now call `set(Derived d, Collection<? extends Consumer> o)` without any compiler warning. The actual unsafe operation happened inside the `get` method.

So the correct fix would be to remove the type parameter from the `get` method and declare what it *really* returns, `Derived`.

---

By the way, what irritates me, is your claim that this code could be compiled under Java 7. Its limited type inference with nested method calls leads to treating the `get` method in a nested invocation context like returning `Base` which can’t be passed to a method expecting a `Derived`. As a consequence, trying to compile this code using a conforming Java 7 compiler will fail as well, but for different reasons.

Answer (score 5):

Well, its not as if Java7 is happy to run it. It gives couple of warnings before giving the error:

```
jatin@jatin-~$ javac -Xlint:unchecked -source 1.7 com/company/Main.java 
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
com/company/Main.java:19: error: no suitable method found for set(Derived,Base)
        set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());
        ^
    method Consumer.set(Base,Derived) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Base cannot be converted to Derived)
    method Consumer.set(Derived,Collection<? extends Consumer>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Base cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Consumer>)

com/company/Main.java:28: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        return (T) new Derived();
                   ^
  required: T
  found:    Derived
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Base declared in method <T>get()
```

The issue is this:

```
set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());
```

When we do `new Consumer().get()`, if we look at signature of `get`. It returns us a Type `T`. We know that `T` somehow extends `Base`. But we do not know what `T` is specifically. It can be anything. So if we cant specifically decide what `T` is, then how can compiler?

One way to tell compiler, is by hardcoding and telling it specifically by: `set(new Derived(), new Consumer().<Derived>get());`.

The reason above is extremely extremely (repeated intentionally) dangerous, is when you try doing this:

```
class NewDerived extends Base {
     public String getName(){return "name";};
}
NewDerived d = new Consumer().<NewDerived>get();
System.out.println(d.getName());
```

In Java7 (or any Java version), it will throw exception at runtime:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.company.Derived cannot be cast to com.company.NewDerived

Because `get` returns an object of type `Derived` but you have mentioned to compiler that it is of `NewDerived`. And it cant convert Derived to NewDerived rightly. This is why it shows a warning.

---

As per the error, now we understand what is wrong with `new Consumer().get()`. It's type is `something that extends base`. Doing `set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());` looks for a method that takes arguments as `Derived (or any super class of it), something that extends Base`.

Now both of your methods qualify for the first argument. As per the second argument `something that extends base`, again both are eligible as that something can be Derived or extend Derived or extend Collection. This is why Java8 throws Error.

As per Java7, its type inference is bit weaker. So it tries doing something similar,

```
Base base = new Consumer().get();
set(new Derived(), base);
```

And again, it cannot find the right method which takes `Derived, Base` as arguments. Hence it throws error but for different reason:

> ```
>     set(new Derived(), new Consumer().get());
>     ^
> method Consumer.set(Base,Derived) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Base cannot be converted to Derived)
> method Consumer.set(Derived,Collection<? extends Consumer>) is not applicabl e
>   (argument mismatch; Base cannot be converted to Collection<? extends Consu mer>)
> ```

PS: Thanks To Holger, for pointing out incompleteness of my answer.

Comment: Actually, the Java 8 compiler isn’t that smart. In fact, `new Consumer().<NewDerived>get()` can be compiled without problems. And the compiler error of the questioner doesn’t tell about how wrong the unchecked operation is, it just says that the method invocation is *ambiguous*. That implies that removing one of the two `set` methods (regardless of which one!) will “fix” the compiler error, even if the result is that the wrong method (expecting a `Collection`) will be called. Or, well, *attempted*, as the cast from `Derived` to `Collection` will fail then.

Comment: Btw. the Java 7 compiler doesn’t give warnings, it gives *errors*. Only the first line in your output is a warning.

Comment: @Holger I completely agree. Thanks for pointing out. There was something else in my mind and I tried pointing a different thing. Thanks. Edited the answer. Thanks again!