# Broken cast on compiling generic method with JDK 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have some legacy code with class `Box` to put and get `Serializable` data into a `Map`, which runs fine on `Oracle JRE 1.8 Update 102` when compiled with `Oracle JDK 1.7 Update 80`. But it don't run properly when I compile it with `Oracle JDK 1.8 Updater 102`. I had some problems with a generic `get` function.

A SSCCE which outputs a formatted date from a `Box` instance using a problematic generic `get` function:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Box implements Serializable{

   private HashMap<String, Serializable> values = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();

   public <T extends Serializable> T get(String key){

      return (T) this.values.get(key);
   }

   public void put(String key,
                   Serializable value){

      this.values.put(key,
                      value);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Box box = new Box();
      box.put("key",
              new Date());

      System.out.println(String.format("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY",
                                       box.get("key")));
   }
}
```

I get the following exception when it is compiled with JDK 1.8 and I run it with JRE 1.8:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>           at Box.main(Box.java:31)

Some Methods like System.out.println produces a compiler error when used with the `get` function

> error: reference to println is ambiguous

while other function runs fine with the `get` function.

The compiler prints out a warning about `unchecked or unsafe operations` and I noticed the main method is compiled to different byte code:

Compiled with 1.7:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #8                  // class Box
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #9                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: ldc           #10                 // String key
      11: new           #11                 // class java/util/Date
      14: dup
      15: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/util/Date."<init>":()V
      18: invokevirtual #13                 // Method put:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;)V
      21: getstatic     #14                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      24: ldc           #15                 // String %1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY
      26: iconst_1
      27: anewarray     #16                 // class java/lang/Object
      30: dup
      31: iconst_0
      32: aload_1
      33: ldc           #10                 // String key
      35: invokevirtual #17                 // Method get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/Serializable;
      38: aastore
      39: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/String.format:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
      42: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      45: return
```

Compiled with 1.8:

```
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #8                  // class Box
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #9                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: ldc           #10                 // String key
      11: new           #11                 // class java/util/Date
      14: dup
      15: invokespecial #12                 // Method java/util/Date."<init>":()V
      18: invokevirtual #13                 // Method put:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/Serializable;)V
      21: getstatic     #14                 // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      24: ldc           #15                 // String %1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY
      26: aload_1
      27: ldc           #10                 // String key
      29: invokevirtual #16                 // Method get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/Serializable;
      32: checkcast     #17                 // class "[Ljava/lang/Object;"
      35: invokestatic  #18                 // Method java/lang/String.format:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
      38: invokevirtual #19                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      41: return
```

**Can somebody explain why it is compiled differently?**

PS: I already fixed it by giving `Class<T> clazz` as additional parameter to the `get` function.

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8072919

Comment: @davida. thank you.

Comment: Regardless of the bug, your generic method is broken.  The `T` is just whatever the caller is expecting; you have no reason to believe this cast will succeed (hence, the unchecked warning.)  A generic method where the type var shows up only in the return type is almost always broken, and provides only the illusion of type safety.  Better to just return Serializable (or Object) and let the caller do the casting.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Do have you read [Holger's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40739761/6673011) before posting? If you have something to add, then feel free to comment this answer.

Comment: @fireandfuel When I commented, there were no answers posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your method

```
public <T extends Serializable> T get(String key){

  return (T) this.values.get(key);
}
```

is fundamentally broken as it basically says “whatever the caller wishes, I will return it, as long as it is assignable to `Serializable`”.

Interestingly, we have similar broken methods every few weeks here, [the last one just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40703415/2711488).

The key point is, if your method promises to return whatever the caller wishes, I could write:

```
Date date=box.get("key");
```

but also

```
String str=box.get("key");
String[] obj=box.get("key");
```

As all these types, `Date`, `String`, or `String[]` are assignable to `Serializable`. Less intuitively, you can even write

```
Object[] obj=box.get("key");
```

despite `Object[]` is not `Serializable`, because there could be a subtype of `Object[]` that is `Serializable`. So the compiler will infer `Object[] & Serializable` for `T` (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36403072/2711488)).

---

The difference between Java 7 and Java 8 is that the Java 7 compiler did not perform this type inference when you put this method invocation as an argument to another invocation (aka “nested method call”). It always used the bounds of the type parameter, i.e. `Serializable` and found that it has to perform a varargs invocation.

In contrast, Java 8 considers all possibilities. It can infer a non-array type and perform a varargs invocation, but it can also infer an array type and pass it directly to the method `String.format(String,Object[])`. The rules are simple, a non-vararg invocation is always preferred.

The fix is simple. Don’t make promises you can’t hold.

```
public Serializable get(String key) {
   return this.values.get(key);
}
```

and let the caller do the type cast explicitly.

```
Date date=(Date)box.get("key");
```

or no cast when an arbitrary object is needed:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY", box.get("key")));
```

which is by the way a convoluted variant of

```
System.out.printf("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY%n", box.get("key"));
```

Alternatively, you can use a `Class` object to specify the expected type:

```
public <T extends Serializable> T get(String key, Class<T> type) {
   return type.cast(this.values.get(key));
}
```

…

```
Date date=box.get("key", Date.class);
```

By the way, referring to `Serializable` explicitly has no real benefit. There are plenty of place, where serializable objects are returned, see `Collections.emptyList()`, for example, without declaring `Serializable`. Consequently, the JRE classes never refer to `Serializable` this way either. Most notably, not even [`ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-) refers to `Serializable` in its signature, but just accepts `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're planning to make this code store a mixture of objects, then I would recommend making the class generic:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Box<T extends Serializable> implements Serializable {

   private HashMap<String, T> values = new HashMap<>();

   public T get(String key){
      return this.values.get(key);
   }

   public void put(String key,
                   T value){

      this.values.put(key,
                      value);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Box<Date> box = new Box<>();
      box.put("key", new Date());

      System.out.println(String.format("%1$td.%1$tm.%1$tY",
                                       box.get("key")));
   }
}
```

Having done that, I'd then ditch `Box` and just use `HashMap<String, ...>`

Comment: It's not the right answer to the question, sure it's a way to solve the problem. As I already written it works with the Class given as parameter.

Comment: btw. The `Box` class was implemented to transport data (a mixture of objects) across multiple modules of the same project. IMHO it's a design flaw.