# Strange ClassCastException in java

Tags: java, java-8, classcastexception

I wrote some code as follow:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printIt(getLong());
        System.out.println("---------");
    }

    public static Object printIt(Object... objects) {
        System.out.println(objects[0].toString());
        return objects[0];
    }

    public static <T> T getLong() {
        return (T)Long.valueOf(1L);
    }
}
```

When I run it, it throws java.lang.ClassCastException as follow:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;  at
>   com.sealinetech.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:5)

But when I debug it with Evaluate Expression, It's OK
[Evaluate Expression is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFQGB.jpg)

My IDE is `intellij`, and the JDK version is jdk1.8.0_144

Comment: You are casting `Long` to `Object[]`. Just don't do it.

Comment: I'd strongly discourage a method signature like your `public static <T> T getLong()`, where you can't infer the type T from any **arguments**. Typical usage has some argument of type T, e.g. `public static <T> T doSomething(T arg)`.

Comment: Exactly as every textbook says. When you ignore “unchecked” warnings, you may get strange `ClassCastException`s at runtime…

Comment: Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40737967/2711488)…

Comment: When I run the application, it throws ClassCastException in the printIt(getLong()) line, but I copy printIt(getLong()) into Evaluate Expression tool then click Evaluate button, it can output result properly, just like the picture above. So I want to know why java use the different type inference method in to ways.

Answer (score 0):

`getLong` method has generic return type. at compile time compiler decides call it with `Object[]` result type, because `printIt` accepts this argument type. in runtime compiler suggestion fails so you get this error: `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object`

you can specify expected type with `printIt(this.<Object>getLong());` (thanks to @CoderinoJavarino)

Comment: In cases like these you can get around by specifying the type explicitly. `printIt(this.<Object>getLong());`

Comment: But why it's OK when I debug it with Evaluate Expression?

Comment: @Rhett : because of different type inference result. Read [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html).

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, the exception comes from the fact that the compiler resolves `T` to be `Object[]` rather than `Object`.

I get that this the code is just a toy example for something more complex. Depending on what the actual scenario is, an alternative solution to what has been already suggested is to constraint the return of type-parameter `T` to a non-array type of choice. In this trivial example perhaps it would be something like `<T extends Number>`.

However, it needs to be pointed out that only looking at the question code, it seems quite clear that given the name of the method, it is going to return `Long` or perhaps a `long` if `null`, is not a valid value, here it simply makes far more sense to get rid of the type-paramter `T` and set the return type as `Long` or `long`.