# Java 8 ambiguous method reference for generic class

Tags: java, generics, java-8, jls

The code below compiles and runs ok in Java 7 but fails to compile in Java 1.8.0 u25:

```
public class GenericTest {

    public static class GenericClass<T> {
        T value;

        public GenericClass(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static class SecondGenericClass<T> {
        T value;

        public SecondGenericClass(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    public static<T >void verifyThat(SecondGenericClass<T> actual, GenericClass<T> matcher) {
    }

    public static<T >void verifyThat(T actual, GenericClass<T> matcher) {
    }

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        verifyThat(new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(""));
    }

}
```

The error message in Java 8 looks like this:

```
Error:(33, 9) java: reference to verifyThat is ambiguous
  both method <T>verifyThat(com.sabre.ssse.core.dsl.GenericTest.SecondGenericClass<T>,com.sabre.ssse.core.dsl.GenericTest.GenericClass<T>) in com.sabre.ssse.core.dsl.GenericTest and method <T>verifyThat(T,com.sabre.ssse.core.dsl.GenericTest.GenericClass<T>) in com.sabre.ssse.core.dsl.GenericTest match
```

I've reviewed all the changes between:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2

But I failed to notice the exact reason for this behaviour.

**Edit:**

Just to answer some comments, it's quite clear that the compiler in both Java 7 and 8 will be able to handle such invocations (with signatures similar to what's left after compile time type erasure:

```
public static void verifyThat(SecondGenericClass actual, GenericClass matcher) {
}

public static void verifyThat(Object actual, GenericClass matcher) {
}

@Test
public void testName() throws Exception {
    verifyThat(new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(""));
}
```

The bytecode generated for both generic methods, and erased is the same, and looks like this:

```
public static verifyThat(Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$SecondGenericClass;Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$GenericClass;)V
public static verifyThat(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$GenericClass;)V
```

**Edit2:**

Compilation under javac 1.8.0_40 fails with the same error

Comment: even with reified generics this would be an issue

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28466925/java-type-inference-reference-is-ambiguous-in-java-8-but-not-java-7

Comment: yes, but according to JLS, the more specific method should be chosen

Comment: @xendoo the problem occurs at runtime. Then, the generic types are erased and it's not possible to determine a difference/ both methods are equally inspecific.

Comment: @SME_Dev `reference to verifyThat is ambiguous` does look like a compiler warning and not like a runtime problem(/exception).

Comment: @xendoo Could you minimize the example? Is the second parameter of `verifyThat` required to reproduce the different behavior between Java7 and Java8?

Comment: @Flow yes, it is necessary, for methods with single parameter compilations works fine `public static<T >void verifyThat(SecondGenericClass<T> actual) {
    }

    public static<T >void verifyThat(T actual) {
    }`

Comment: After getting on a computer and testing your code, I get no warning or errors in Eclipse Luna 4.4 using Java 8u31 - [picture](http://gyazo.com/2a71ea25fe91bf68f3cdc7eb0ea3c6ce)

Comment: @VinceEmigh Eclipse incremental compiler differs a lot from javac. I'm using IntelliJ which uses javac.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JLS, chapter §15.12.2.5 Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) is a hard read but contains an interesting summary:

> The informal intuition is that one method is more specific than another if any invocation handled by the first method could be passed on to the other one without a compile-time type error.

We can easily disprove this for your case with the following example:

```
GenericTest.<String>verifyThat( // invokes the first method
    new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(""));
GenericTest.<SecondGenericClass<String>>verifyThat( // invokes the second
    new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(null));
```

so there is no most specific method here, however, as the example shows, it is possible to invoke either method using arguments that make the other method *inapplicable*.

In Java 7 it was easier to make a method inapplicable due to the limited attempts (of the compiler) to find type arguments to make more methods applicable (aka limited type inference). The expression `new SecondGenericClass<>("")` had the type `SecondGenericClass<String>` inferred from its argument `""` and that’s it. So for the invocation `verifyThat(new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(""))` the arguments had the type `SecondGenericClass<String>` and `GenericClass<String>` which made the method `<T> void verifyThat(T,GenericClass<T>)` inapplicable.

Note that there is an example of an ambiguous invocation which exhibits the ambiguity under Java 7 (and even Java 6): `verifyThat(null, null);` will provoke a compiler error when using `javac`.

But Java 8 has [Invocation Applicability Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1) (there we have a difference to JLS 7, an entirely new chapter…) which allows the compiler to choose type arguments which make a method candidate applicable (which works through nested invocations). You can find such type arguments for your special case, you can even find a type argument which fits both,

```
GenericTest.<Object>verifyThat(new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<>(""));
```

is unambiguously ambiguous (in Java 8), even Eclipse agrees on that. In contrast, the invocation

```
verifyThat(new SecondGenericClass<>(""), new GenericClass<String>(""));
```

is specific enough to render the second method inapplicable and invoke the first method, which gives us a hint about what’s going on in Java 7 where the type of `new GenericClass<>("")` is fixed as `GenericClass<String>` just like with `new GenericClass<String>("")`.

---

The bottom line is, it’s not the choosing of the most specific method which changed from Java 7 to Java 8 (significantly), but the applicability due to the improved type inference. Once both methods are applicable, the invocation is ambiguous as neither method is more specific than the other.

Answer (score 1):

In resolving which method to use in the case where multiple methods are applicable, **"...the types of an invocation's arguments cannot, in general, be inputs to the analysis."**  The Java 7 spec is missing this qualification.

If you substitute `T` in the second definition of `verifyThat` for `SecondGenericClass` the signatures match.

In other words, imagine attempting to call the second definition of `verifyThat` like this:

```
SecondGenericClass<String> t = new SecondGenericClass<String>("foo");
GenericTest.verifyThat(t, new GenericClass<String>("bar"));
```

At runtime, there would be no way to determine which version of `verifyThat` to call since the type of variable `t` is a valid substitution for both `SecondGenericClass<T>` and `T`.

Note that if Java had reified generics (and it will someday), in this example one method signature is not more specific than the other.  Closing loopholes...

Comment: The bytecode generated for those functions looks like that, and according to the jls, compiler should use more specific method if one of the parameters is subtype of another:

`public static verifyThat(Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$SecondGenericClass;Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$GenericClass;)V

  public static verifyThat(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/sabre/ssse/core/dsl/GenericTest$GenericClass;)V` <br>

Comment: 15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method states: 

_"The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen"_

... _"A type S is more specific than a type T for any expression if S <: T "_ ...

Comment: by all accounts, Java 7 type inference was weaker in this respect.  if you are looking at a Java 7 spec, that may be the source of the confusion.

Comment: I'm looking at Java 8 spec, and by the way, the type inference here is weaker in Java 8, it finds two methods applicable, while Java 7 finds only one.

Comment: Java 7 would have given you a runtime time warning I believe, Java 8 is preventing it at compile time.  The examples in the spec all point to concrete types, e.g., ColoredPoint vs. Point, and not to generics.

Comment: "To check for applicability, the types of an invocation's arguments cannot, in general, be inputs to the analysis."

Comment: Note that the Java 7 spec does not have this qualification.

Comment: _"Instead, the input to the applicability check is a list of argument expressions, which can be checked for compatibility with potential target types, even if the ultimate types of the expressions are unknown."_

In this case the expression passed as argument can be easily used to resolve the compatibility with the signature

Comment: I believe this is a reference to the types of the supplied arguments and not of the method parameter type definitions.

Comment: @xendo `S <: T` indicates [proper subtype](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10), and both `SecondGeneric<T>` and `Object` are proper supertypes. `S <1 T` is for direct subtypes

Comment: I updated my question with example of similar functions after erasing the generic type T, bytecode generated for them is identical to previous functions. But this time compilation succedes in both Java 7 and 8

Comment: when they do reify generics in Java, your new code will still be valid, the generic form will not.

Comment: @VinceEmigh still, the SecondGeneric<T> is proper subtype of Object, and should be used to choose more specific method

Comment: @jkschneider FYI, Java 7 does not return any runtime/compile time warnings

Comment: @VinceEmigh I assume that you are using eclipse compiler?

Comment: This is far away from being a valid explanation. At runtime, the type of `t` doesn’t matter as the selection of the method happens at *compile-time*. Ranting about type erasure doesn’t really help; there wouldn’t be any difference with reified types .