# Generic return type upper bound - interface vs. class - surprisingly valid code

Tags: java, generics, java-8

*This is a real-world example from a 3rd party library API, but simplified.*

*Compiled with Oracle JDK 8u72*

Consider these two methods:

```
<X extends CharSequence> X getCharSequence() {
    return (X) "hello";
}

<X extends String> X getString() {
    return (X) "hello";
}
```

Both report an "unchecked cast" warning - I get why. The thing that baffles me is why can I call

```
Integer x = getCharSequence();
```

and it compiles? The compiler should know that `Integer` does not implement `CharSequence`. The call to

```
Integer y = getString();
```

gives an error (as expected)

> ```
> incompatible types: inference variable X has incompatible upper bounds java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String
> ```

Can someone explain why would this behaviour be considered valid? How would it be useful?

The client does not know that this call is unsafe - the client's code compiles without warning. Why wouldn't the compile warn about that / issue an error?

Also, how is it different from this example:

```
<X extends CharSequence> void doCharSequence(List<X> l) {
}

List<CharSequence> chsL = new ArrayList<>();
doCharSequence(chsL); // compiles

List<Integer> intL = new ArrayList<>();
doCharSequence(intL); // error
```

Trying to pass `List<Integer>` gives an error, as expected:

> ```
> method doCharSequence in class generic.GenericTest cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: java.util.List<X>
>   found: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>
>   reason: inference variable X has incompatible bounds
>     equality constraints: java.lang.Integer
>     upper bounds: java.lang.CharSequence
> ```

If that is reported as an error, why `Integer x = getCharSequence();` isn't?

Comment: interesting! casting on the LHS `Integer x = getCharSequence();` will compile, but casting on the RHS `Integer x = (Integer) getCharSequence();` fails compile

Comment: What version of the java compiler are you using? Please specify this info in the question.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner can't see why that matters - this is a question directly about the JLS.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Because the type inference mechanism has changed for java8

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner - I tagged the question already with [java-8], but I added the compiler version in the post now.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

`CharSequence` is an `interface`. Therefore even if `SomeClass` does not implement `CharSequence` it would be perfectly possible to create a class

```
class SubClass extends SomeClass implements CharSequence
```

Therefore you can write

```
SomeClass c = getCharSequence();
```

because the inferred type `X` is the intersection type `SomeClass & CharSequence`.

This is a bit odd in the case of `Integer` because `Integer` is final, but `final` doesn't play any role in these rules. For example you can write

```
<T extends Integer & CharSequence>
```

On the other hand, `String` is not an `interface`, so it would be impossible to extend `SomeClass` to get a subtype of `String`, because java does not support multiple-inheritance for classes.

With the `List` example, you need to remember that generics are neither covariant nor contravariant. This means that if `X` is a subtype of `Y`, `List<X>` is neither a subtype nor a supertype of `List<Y>`. Since `Integer` does not implement `CharSequence`, you cannot use `List<Integer>` in your `doCharSequence` method.

You can, however get this to compile

```
<T extends Integer & CharSequence> void foo(List<T> list) {
    doCharSequence(list);
}
```

If you have a method that *returns* a `List<T>` like this:

```
static <T extends CharSequence> List<T> foo()
```

you can do

```
List<? extends Integer> list = foo();
```

Again, this is because the inferred type is `Integer & CharSequence` and this is a subtype of `Integer`.

Intersection types occur implicitly when you specify multiple bounds (e.g. `<T extends SomeClass & CharSequence>`).

For further information, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeBound) is the part of the JLS where it explains how type bounds work. You can include multiple interfaces, e.g.

```
<T extends String & CharSequence & List & Comparator>
```

but only the first bound may be a non-interface.

Comment: I had no idea you could put an `&` in the generic definition. +1

Comment: @flkes You can put more than one, but only the first argument can be a non-interface. `<T extends String & List & Comparator>` is ok but `<T extends String & Integer>` is not, because `Integer` is not an interface.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul, the `foo(List<T> list)` is especially creative! Still, I don't get how that can be practically useful for client and API provider to use such generic API. With `<X extends CharSequence> X getCharSequence()` the only thing the provider promises is that the returned object implements `CharSequence`. The client has no way of knowing what other types it is valid to cast to. It might cast to `SomeClass` or to `OtherClass` - getting a runtime exception. Would you have an example where this could be useful? To me it just seems dangerous, weakening the compile-time checking.

Comment: @AdamMichalik I agree with you. In my opinion, methods like `<T> List<T> someMethod()` are dangerous. It says that the caller can decide what type the method returns without passing any information to the method at all - which makes absolutely no sense. I've seen it in 3rd party APIs too but I think it's really bad practice. On the other hand, if T appears in the argument list too it's ok. E.g `<T> List<T> shuffle(List<T> list)` makes perfect sense. So it's that specific type method that's unsafe, not generics in general.

Comment: In fact, the compile-time checking is cancelled out solely by the unchecked cast (and, regarding the `SomeClass` example: The implementation can not sensibly return an instance of `X` in any case). Maybe adding a hint at [the JLS section 4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-TypeBound) could be worthwhile, where it is made clear that a `TypeBound` may contain at most one `ClassType` (but multiple `InterfaceType`s).

Comment: @PaulBoddington There is some practical use for these methods. For example if the type is not actually used for stored data. Examples for this are `Collections.emptyList()` as well as `Optional.empty()`. These return implementations of a generic interface, but do not store anything.

Comment: @StefanDollase Yes that's a good point. My comment is misleading. I like those examples as they show that type erasure has benefits. You couldn't share a single instance for `Collections.emptyList()` in C# because the type can be queried at runtime.

Comment: There are only two kinds of possible correct implementations for a method like `<X extends CharSequence> X getCharSequence()`, first, `return null;`, second, `throw …;`. Having little use is not a good criteria for ruling out actually syntactical valid constructs—the rules are already complicated enough. Note the difference between this method returning a caller-chosen type and the useful methods `Collections.emptyList()` and `Optional.empty()` returning a type, *parametrized* by the caller. There is another family of valid uses, see (the `private` method)  `Collectors.throwingMerger()`…

Comment: Or `Comparator.naturalOrder()`or `Function.identity()`…

Comment: @Holger I guess you could also do `while (true);`, although that's even more pointless. When I made my comment about bad practice I was thinking of something like `<T> T getFromId(long id)`, although that's obviously not what the comment says. In these cases, I think returning `Object` and forcing the client to cast is better. My last SO answer but 2 has a method `static <T> Collector<T, ?, List<T>> toShuffledList()`, so I don't know why I said it was bad practice!

Comment: Mmmm, this answer sounds 'logical', however there's no way for `Integer x = getCharSequence()` to **NOT** be a compiler bug, since `Integer` does not implement `CharSequence`.

Comment: @Paul Boddington: that’s not unusual to think about the bad practice of methods like `<T> T getFromId(long id)` as there are several examples of that on SO, especially in the Java 8 context, where that backfires (even more)…

Comment: @PaulBoddington Sorry, that was me.. While your answer is logical and explains generics bound types correctly (as well as generics not covariance), I think it fails to explain why `Integer x = getCharSequence()` actually compiles, when it's obvious that it's an error in the compiler type inference system. (I removed the downvote by now)

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: there *could* be a type that extends both, `Integer` and `CharSequence` and as this answer explains, the fact that `Integer` is `final` is not considered. It’s new in the Java 8 type inference, that you don’t need to know an actual type for that hypothetical type.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Thanks for explaining the downvote. I guess the reason they didn't take `final` into account with these rules is that they're complicated enoungh.

Comment: @Holger Do you known why `Integer a = (Integer) getCharSequence();` doesn't compile?

Comment: And nobody says that a class being `final` at compile-time will be `final` at runtime.

Comment: @Paul Boddington: no, that’s a strange thing as the cast should provide a target type just like the assignment. I just checked that it will work if you pass the invocation to another one, letting the parameter provide the target type.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner : [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28466925/2711488) is a similar example where the compiler assumes that there *could* be a type that implements `Base` and `Collection` making an invalid invocation valid from the compiler’s point of view. The only difference being that `Base` is not `final`, but as said, `final` is not considered by the type system.

Comment: @Holger I'm starting to learn about *poly expressions* and the role they play in Java8's type inference mechanism. However, despite there *might* exist a type that extends both `Integer` and `CharSequence`, I believe the compiler should check that the type at the left of the `=`  sign of the assignment should actually match the type at the right of the `=` sign, no matter if it's an intersection type or not, but *especially* if the type is not an intersection type.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: the point here is, the method `getCharSequence()` promises to return whatever `X` the caller needs, that includes returning a type extending `Integer` and implementing `CharSequence` if the caller needs it and under this promise, it’s correct to allow assigning the result to `Integer`. It’s the method `getCharSequence()` which is broken as it doesn’t keep its promise, but that’s not the compiler’s fault.

Comment: @Holger I think I understand the mechanism now, thanks for the examples and for taking the time to explain it. Anyways, given I have the class `class Whatever {}`, I fail to see how compiling `Whatever youWant = getCharSequence();` doesn't throw an error. I understand that the method `getCharSequence()` is broken and that the cast inside it is really bad practice. But I think that this opens the door to massive heap pollution. I perfectly understand that `StringBuilder sb = getCharSequence()` compiles fine, though. That's my point.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: in this scenario, there is no heap pollution. The case you’re unwilling to accept is where the code will clearly fail with a `ClassCastException`, so there won’t be a heap pollution. A heap pollution will happen if the returned value is kept in a variable with a non-reifyable type, but that’s exactly the scenario where the compiler can’t determine the (in)correctness anyway (where we have a type variable rather than `Integer`). The scenario here, where the human reader says “that’s obviously wrong”, is a corner case of a more general issue.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner: Keep in mind that with a correct implementation of `getCharSequence()` (e.g. returning `null`, throwing an exception, never completing or returning the correct thing via magic), the compiled code, including the assignment to `Integer` will be correct.

Comment: @AdamMichalik "With <X extends CharSequence> X getCharSequence() the only thing the provider promises is that the returned object implements CharSequence" No, it promises to return object of any type `X` which implements `CharSequence` which _the client_ chooses by calling `<X>getCharSequence()`. "The client has no way of knowing what other types it is valid to cast to. It might cast to SomeClass or to OtherClass - getting a runtime exception." How is this different from any other method which doesn't return a primitive or a final class?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - that's the point that it seems to promise to return **anything** the client chooses, but it has no way of knowing what the client has chosen and how to comply with that choice. In my example the client has chosen `Integer` - how would the provider know that and how would it return an object that extends `Integer` and implements `CharSequence`, while a different client could call choosing `Boolean` for `X`? My point is that the client does not know that this call is unsafe - the client's code compiles without warning.

Comment: @AdamMichalik No, in your example the client has chosen `Integer & CharSequence`. To choose `Integer` they'd need to write `Integer x = <Integer>getCharSequence()`, which will fail to compile as expected.

Comment: @AdamMichalik For the first: it doesn't _seem_ to promise this, it _does_ promise this. It just has no way to fulfill that promise (except the ones already mentioned: returning `null`, throwing or looping). This is very different from saying it only promises "that the returned object implements CharSequence": there are plenty of ways to fulfill _that_ promise!

Comment: Was not able to understand the reasoning behind `even if SomeClass does not implement CharSequence it would be perfectly possible to create a class`. If a class uses the keyword implement then it will have to implement the interface otherwise such a class would not compile. What am I missing?

Comment: @AseemBansal I'm saying that just because `Someclass` doesn't implement `CharSequence`, it doesn't mean some subclass can't implement `CharSequence`. This is different from classes. If `SomeClass` doesn't extend `SomeOtherClass`, no subclass of `SomeClass` can either.

Answer (score 60):

The type that is inferred by your compiler prior to the assignment for `X` is `Integer & CharSequence`. This type *feels* weird, because `Integer` is final, but it's a perfectly valid type in Java. It is then cast to `Integer`, which is perfectly OK.

There is exactly one possible value for the `Integer & CharSequence` type: `null`. With the following implementation:

```
<X extends CharSequence> X getCharSequence() {
    return null;
}
```

The following assignment will work:

```
Integer x = getCharSequence();
```

Because of this possible value, there's no reason why the assignment should be wrong, even if it is obviously useless. A warning would be useful.

#### The real problem is the API, not the call site

In fact, I've recently blogged about this [API design anti pattern](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/04/30/this-common-api-technique-is-actually-an-anti-pattern/). You should (almost) never design a generic method to return arbitrary types because you can (almost) never guarantee that the inferred type will be delivered. An exception are methods like `Collections.emptyList()`, in case of which the emptiness of the list (and generic type erasure) is the reason why any inference for `<T>` will work:

```
public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```