# How is a type argument inferred for a generic method invocation?

Tags: java, generics, java-8, java-7, type-inference

Having a method like this?

```
public <P, T extends List<P>> T getAwesomeList() {
    // ...
}
```

How come this compiles without any warnings?

```
Set<String> test = getAwesomeList();
```

I think it has something to do with generic erasure, but not sure how come this is not picked up by the compiler. This happens on Java 7, on 8 you do get a compilation error.

What has changed on J8 for this to not compile?

**Update:**

After double checking, it also compiles on Java 8.

Comment: @JornVernee Although it might look like a duplicate of that, it is not.  This code has no raw types that I can see.

Comment: @VGR You have to do an explicit cast in the method `getAwesomeList`. So there is an unchecked cast. Or can you come up with a proper return value?

Comment: Your method has no arguments, so there's nothing to tell the compiler that the types it infers are not suitable. If you want to get an error, either supply method arguments or state explicitly the generic type (this won't allow the compiler to infer).

Comment: @pablisco What exactly do you return from the method? The way I see it, you can only return a `T` (which is-a `List`) and this most definitely would result in a compilation error. Show your code inside the `getAwesomeList` method? (Edit : I tried your code out and it doesn't compile!!!)

Comment: FYI : This code doesn't compile on JDK 1.8 for the exact same reason the OP wants it not to compile : *Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to Set<String>*. Not sure what the question is here.

Comment: @CKing, it compiles fine in Java 8.

Comment: @VGR It's mentioned in the comments of the dupe, it compiles even if you have no raw types and remove the unchecked cast (you can return `null` for instance).

Comment: @VHS Something [fishy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFXa9.png) is going on here. Will check it out later. For now it doesn't compile for me :)

Comment: @CKing, I looked at the screenshot of your error. That is because your method is non-static and you are calling it from a static context (static main method).

Comment: @VHS What are you talking about? I create an instance of `GenericReturnType` and then call the method in it : See -> `Set<String> test = new GenericReturnType().getAwesomeList(); `. I wouldn't take the efforts to post an image unless I eliminated the obvious. I should get the same error even if I call `getAwesomeList` from a non static method FYI.

Comment: @CKing: you are using *Eclipse*, which has its own compiler, which is infamous for its type inference problems. As a fun fact, it does compile the code in Java 7 level, but not in Java 8 level in my installation.

Comment: @Holger I see. I keep forgetting eclipse has its own compiler since I rarely face such issues. (It doesn't compile for me at Java 1.7 level as well)

Comment: @CKing, sorry oversight at my end. I do now see that you are calling the method on the instance of the class. I am using Eclipse Neon with Java 8 compiler and it compiles fine.

Comment: @VHS Yup. Looks like inconsistent behavior in eclipse rather than the JDK :).

Comment: @CKing No [fish](http://imgur.com/a/NXpPj) here.

Comment: After running a lot of tests, I am convinced that this happens because List and Set are interfaces, so the inferred common type is Object (since any descendant of non-final class *might* implement an interface).  Change the method to `public <P, T extends AbstractList<P>> T getAwesomeList()` and change the calling code to `HashSet<String> test = getAwesomeList();` and you will see the compilation error one would expect to see, because no theoretical inference is possible.

Comment: @VGR: the inferred type is more like “`Set<String>&List<Object>`”, though the actual parameterization of `List` is irrelevant here.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38095037/2711488) shows some explicit parameterizations to illustrate the intersection types.

Comment: The real answer is that due to type erasure the generics are completely lost and the compiler is horrible with inferring stuff, so it just eats any casting without checking the type bounds.

Comment: @pablisco No. It compiles without warnings (unlike many Stack Overflow Java generics questions) and is sound.

Comment: @pablisco Generics are always lost in type erasure (that's what it does) and the compiler is not horrible - the code will never fail. When you write a generic return type without enforcing it nothing can go wrong, so the compiler doesn't complain.