# Why the code with such generic bound is compiled

Tags: java, generics

In the next piece of code I have a parameterized method which creates an `ArrayList`, cast it to `<T extends List<Integer>>`. And that list is getting assigned to a variable of type `MyClass`

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        MyClass s = createList(); // compiler should find here an error
    }

    private static <T extends List<Integer>> T createList()
    {
        return (T) new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
}
```

I expect that the compiler won't process that code and will show me an error. But the class gets compiled and in runtime the app predictably throws a cast exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class
>   java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
>   (java.util.ArrayList and java.lang.String are in module java.base of
>   loader 'bootstrap')   at pkgname.MyClass.main(MyClass.java:9)

If I change generic's signature to `T extends ArrayList` it works as I expect - shows compiling error:

> Error:(9, 31) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has
>   incompatible upper bounds pkgname.MyClass,java.util.ArrayList

So that works only with interfaces.
And if I try to assign the returning value to classes like `Integer`, `Number`, `String` etc. or make `MyClass` final, then I'm getting a warning

```
Though assignment is formal correct, it could lead to ClassCastException at runtime. Expected: 'String', actual: 'List<Integer> & String'
```

Yes, the casting shows a warning `Unchecked cast: 'java.unil.ArrayList' to 'T'` but why does the compiler fails to detect wrong assinment if I use an interface as a generic's param?

I suspect that when I use an interface as a generic's bound, a compiler might assume that even though `MyClass` doesn't inherit the interface yet, one of MyClass's descendants might, so that code might be correct. Buy when the class is `final` - there is definitely no chance that returned value can be assigned to `MyClass`

Comment: Good explanation why `javac` allows this for methods and not for types is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095037/1602555)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *could* be a `T` that both `extends List<Integer>` and extends `MyClass` (for example a `class MyListClass extends MyClass implements List<Integer>`.

The compiler doesn't *look into* the `createList` method to figure out what it returns, it just trusts that it does what the prototype describes.

Since you use an unchecked cast inside the method body, you are *allowed* to break the type system this way. And that's why you get a warning about that unchecked cast.

Effectively the unchecked cast means you disable the type check at that line and therefore can implement a return type that you don't actually fulfill (you don't *actually* return a `MyListClass` as described above, you just *claim* that you do).

The reason this doesn't work for non-interface types is that the type system doesn't allow a type that is two unrelated non-interface types at the same time (a thing can't be a `String` and a `MyClass` at the same type).

Comment: Yes, the last paragraph in my question - exactly such assuming, but why can't `javac` detect a case when a class is `final`? In that case the class definitely does not `implements List<Integer>` and it can't have any descendants which would implement the interface

Comment: @Michel_T: it probably *could*, but the specs don't require it to. There's multiple reasons not to enforce that: 1.) it might be expensive to compute that information and requiring that from all compilers for little benefit is not worth it. 2.) there *might* be a situation where the `final` state of a class might change in other revisions (a `final` class turning non-`final` is [not considered to break binary compatibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.2)!).

Comment: That's an intersting point about `final` compatibility. I've never met it before. Thanks for the opinion.