# Java generic, method that returns T where <T extends String> cannot return string

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have found following code:

```
public class Ex7 {
    static class Translator<T1, T2 extends String> {
        T2 translate(T1 what) {
           return what + " ";
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            new Translator<Integer, String>().translate(1)
       );
    }
}
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't compile, since T2 is String and i want to return
String from the method "translate", compiler says that it expects T2 instead of String, but i understand that T2 is string as is is stated here:

```
new Translator<Integer, String>().translate(1)
```

Can someone please, explain this to me?

Comment: `T2 extends String` is legal, but nonsensical: nothing can `String`, because it's final. The only thing this method could safely return is `null`.

Comment: Since you want to return a string and as mention String is final T2 is irrelevant here and might be removed from the declaration and the method should be "hardcoded" to return String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T2 extends String` is legal, but nonsensical. Nothing extends `String`, because it's a final class. However, the compiler doesn't stop you writing this because it doesn't consider `final`-ness of the bounding class.

Put `String` aside for a second, and consider these classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

If you declare a class like this:

```
static class Translator<T1, T2 extends A> {
    T2 translate(T1 what) {
       return new A();
    }
}
```

you can hopefully see why this would be illegal:

```
Translator<String, B> t = new Translator<>();
B result = t.translate("");
```

Here, `result` is expected to be an instance of `B`; but the implementation of the method means that it's returning an `A`. This is guaranteed to fail, so it's forbidden.

The compiler doesn't consider `String` any differently from `A` in this regard: there *might* be a subclass, so it bans you from returning a `String` where a subclass *might* be expected to be returned.

Comment: the problem is, if we leave your code as it is and we only change translate method so that it returns new B() it wont compile either ...

Comment: @PrezesKozłowski correct. Because the caller might expect it to return any subclass of `A`, perhaps `C` which is a direct subclass of `A`. You can't actually return anything from the method other than literal `null`.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095037/2711488), which demonstrates that even expecting `List<Integer>` as return value of `translate` would be valid, as the caller might infer `X extends String&List<Integer>` for `T2` without violating the `T2 extends String` constraint. Of course, the implementation of `translate` can't fulfill this expectation, as correctly said, "*You can't actually return anything from the method other than literal `null`*". The only alternatives are throwing an exception or never returning (i.e. looping endlessly).

Answer (score 0):

> since T2 is String

This is the essential part. A generic class is a template for instances that can use various types. If the method signature defines `T2` it remains generic even if it has a constraint like `extends String`. `T2` is never `String`, it is some unknown type that should extend `String`.

If the generic class does not consider that and returns a `String` it violates the method definition of returning `T2`.