# Why assignment result of method with generic return type extends any interface to any type is allowed?

Tags: java, generics

Why first assignment in main method is allowed?

```
public class Test {
  interface AnyInterface {}

  public static <T extends AnyInterface> T test1() { return null; }

  public static AnyInterface test2() { return null; }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = test1(); // ok. WHY?
    String b = test2(); // compile error
  }
}
```

Inspired from this talk: https://youtu.be/mNyQYTp-Njw?t=37m39s

Comment: Found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402646/generic-return-type-upper-bound-interface-vs-class-surprisingly-valid-code