# Filling a List<? extends Foo>

Tags: java, java-8, bounded-wildcard

Having a collection of abstract objects: `Set<Foo> foes;`

I want to have a method like this:

```
List<? extends Foo> getFoesByType(TypeEnum type);
```

I've tried:

```
List<? extends Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(Foo f : foes) {
        if(f.getType() == type) {
            switch(type) {
            case TYPE1:
                f = (FooType1) f;
                break;
            case TYPE2:
                /*...*/
            }

            result.add(f);  
            /*The method add(capture#1-of ?) in the type 
            List<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Foo)*/
        } 
}  

return result;
```

But I get an error.

I want to be able to do this: `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1);` Which would be the correct way?

Comment: Why do you need to cast to a child class before inserting into the list? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @QBrute Maybe the wildcard is not what I should use. I just want to get  a list of concrete classes. `type` is associated to the concrete class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only safe way is by adding a `Class` parameter to support type checking at runtime:

```
private <T extends Foo> List<T> getFooesByType(EnumType type, Class<T> type) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Foo f : foes) {
        if(f.getType() == type) {
            switch(type) {
                case TYPE1:
                    // do something, cast is not necessary
                    break;
                case TYPE2:
                    /*...*/
            }
            result.add(type.cast(f)); // safe cast
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

to be called like

```
List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1, FooType1.class);
```

This is the only way to ensure that the list elements are of the caller specified type. On the other hand, this makes the requirement that `T` is a subtype of `Foo` obsolete.

You could change `<T extends Foo>` to `<T>` raising the flexibility of the method,
e.g. `List<Object> list = getFooesByType(TYPE1, Object.class);` would be legal as well.

Comment: Why your line is a "safe cast" and mine is not? Have a look into `Class#cast` implementation: `return (T)paramObject;`. So, same question to you: "this method cannot guaranty that the elements are of the `T` the caller expects. [...] Now, how does your method hold its promise?"

Comment: @Stefan Warminski: you have to look at [the lines before that](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Class.java#3368)…

Comment: @Stefan Holger is right. By using the second argument, the compiler won't allow i.e. `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE2, FooType2.class);`, though `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE2, FooType1.class);` will compile fine, which will have the effect of casting `Foo` objects to `FooType1` while taking the action for `FooType2`... So this all points to deeper design problems, IMO. Btw, Holger, you should rename the second argument to something like `clazz`...

Comment: In fact, I don't need that `EnumType` anymore, it can work just with the class type: `if (type.isInstance(f))  result.add(type.cast(f));`

Comment: @LiLou_: indeed, if the only purpose of the `enum` was to denote the desired type, class literals are the better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make your method generic:

```
private <T extends Foo> List<T> getFooesByType(EnumType type) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Foo f : foes) {
        if(f.getType() == type) {
            switch(type) {
            case TYPE1:
                // do something, cast is not necessary
                break;
            case TYPE2:
                /*...*/
            }

            result.add((T) f); // cast here
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would you call this generic method? I suppose in the call you need to specify somehow what `T` is?

Comment: It is type inference. By calling `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1);` the compiler get the information from `List<FooType1>`. You can also specify the generic type by a 2nd parameter `Class<T> fooClass` and invoke it like this: `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1, FooType1.class);`

Comment: This is broken. You get an unchecked warning at the `(T)` cast for a good reason: this method cannot guaranty that the elements are of the `T` the caller expects. In fact, I can even write `List<Runnable> list = getFooesByType(TYPE1);` without a compiler error, as then, `T` will be `Foo&Runnable`. Now, how does your method hold its promise?

Comment: `<T extends Foo>` will not allow `Runnable`. But you're right, it is not sure that an instance of `Foo` with `EnumType.TYPE1` extending `FooType1`. This is not part of OP's question but could be easily solved if you add the parameter `Class<T> fooClass` and check the `Foo`s with `fooClass.isAssignableFrom(f.getClass())`

Comment: `<T extends Foo>` will not allow `Runnable`, but as said, it allows `Foo&Runnable`. I should have written `List<? extends Runnable> list = getFooesByType(EnumType.TYPE1);` to be precise, this *does* compile with Java 8. See “[Generic return type upper bound - interface vs. class - surprisingly valid code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36402646/2711488)”. But stay at `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1);` if you wish and explain, how the compiler should distinguish that from `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE2);`…

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. `? extends Foo` means that there could be any child of `Foo` class. You don't know what exactly it is and that's why you can't add to `List<? extends Foo>`.

But you can create array list and assign it to List and then return.

```
List<? extends Foo> getFoesByType(TypeEnum type) {
    List<Foo> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // add something to result list
    return result;
}
```

Comment: But then when I invoke the method like this: `List<FooType1> foesType1 = getFooesByType(TypeEnum.TYPE1);` I get the same error as before.

Comment: @LiLou_ in this case you don't need wildcards. You can use just `List<Foo>`. You will be able to add Foo successors to such list.