# Reference to X is ambiguous, but compiles in Eclipse

Tags: java

This issue may be similar to [Reference is ambiguous with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361513/reference-is-ambiguous-with-generics), but I guess it is a little different.

In this case

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTest test = new MyTest();
        test.add(test::method);
    }

    public void add(Interface1 i1) {
    }

    public <T extends Interface2> void add(T i2) {
    }

    private void method() {
    }

    public interface Interface1 {
        void method1();
    }
    public interface Interface2 {
        boolean isMethod2();
        void setMethod2(boolean required);
    }

}
```

, it is compiled with Eclipse `Neon.2`, but not with javac `1.8.0_121` or `1.8.0_152`, giving an error:

> MyTest.java:5: error: reference to add is ambiguous
>
> ```
>    test.add(test::method);
>        ^
> ```
>
> both method add(Interface1) in MyTest and method add(T) in MyTest match
>
> where T is a type-variable:
>
> T extends Interface2 declared in method add(T)

However, if

```
public <T extends Interface2> void add(T i2) {
```

is changed to:

```
public void add(Interface2 i2) {
```

then it id compiled by `javac`.

So, is it correct for javac to say `T` is a type-variable, and is not sub-type of `Interface2`, so it complains about ambiguity, and if so, then Eclipse is wrong?

Comment: eclipse has its' own compiler, and the official Java compiler is the "correct one". So yes, it's correct to say that Eclipse is wrong.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm sorry, why exactly is `javac` the correct one?

Comment: @biziclop Because the eclipse project has no (or minimal) involvement with the specification of Java (while Oracle **owns** Java). See also, [What is the difference between javac and the Eclipse compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061654/what-is-the-difference-between-javac-and-the-eclipse-compiler). From the linked questions' top answer, *One notable difference is that the Eclipse compiler lets you run code that didn't actually properly compile.*

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So? I'm sorry, I still don't see your point. If `javac` is by definition the correct one, why do they keep fixing bugs in it? :) Surely whichever compiler conforms to the JLS is the correct one. Sometimes it's the Eclipse compiler, sometimes it's `javac`. In this case I suspect `javac` is the buggy one. (And the quote about the Eclipse compiler letting you run code that didn't compile is irrelevant here, that refers to a different thing.)

Comment: I suspect `javac` complains about ambiguity because `T extends Interface2` might in theory resolve `T` to an `Interface3` that extends `Interface2`, defines default methods for `isMethod2()` and `setMethod2()`, and then declares an abstract `void method3()`.

Comment: @biziclop `javac` isn't entirely buggy, `T` could be a Type that implements both `Interface1` and `Interface2`, and in that case both `add(T i2)` and `add(Interface1 i1)` are valid

Comment: @niceman Yes, that is definitely a potential source of ambiguity. But in this specific case we know it doesn't happen.

Comment: ofcourse this doesn't mean the eclipse compiler is entirely wrong because there is not `T` that implements both interfaces in anyway here, what we have here is different strategies

Comment: @niceman, even if you add `Interface3` to extends both `Interface1` and `Interface2`, and change the method signature of `i2` to `public void add(Interface3 i2) {`, it will compile with `javac`.

Comment: @AhmedAshour You need to make `Interface3` a functional interface with a `void methodX()`, then it will be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to the stack exchange discussion you mentioned (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5365419/16595881) solves your issue.

To comment on the comments on this question, Oracle did not define a Java SE compiler as the 'correct' compiler for Java SE, but rather Oracle defined the specifications that a Java SE compiler must adhere to. In order for a Java SE compiler to be 'correct' (i.e. in order for something to be a Java SE compiler), it must implement those specifications. Just because Oracle defined both the specifications and a (questionable) implementation of those specifications, it is not guaranteed that the implementation is 'correct', although it likely is. In this case, your `javac` compiler correctly implements the Java SE language specifications, but Eclipse's compiler does not (it might now, being 5 years later).

Also, `javac` is a command-line tool  on your PATH that points to an executable binary that can be arbitrary. This means instead of being a compiler, the binary executed by calling `javac` might simply print "I am not a Java SE compiler" or instead might produce nasal demons. The point is that the `javac` binary is not necessarily Oracle's implementation of the Java SE compiler specifications. For example, it could be an implementation by Sun (which was bought by Oracle in 2009) or by OpenJDK, to name a few. Anyway...

In the second definition of `MyTest#add`, `T` extends `Interface2`, but that does not limit `T` from also extending `Interface1`, because classes can implement multiple interfaces. So, it is possible to construct a class that implements both interfaces then pass one of its instances as the argument into `MyTest#add`, in which case both definitions of the method would be valid candidates, with neither being more appropriate then the other. Consider the following code example, where we replace the interfaces with abstract classes:

```
public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyTest test = new MyTest();
        test.add(test.new Abstract1() {
            @Override
            void method1() {
                test.method();
            }
        });
    }

    public void add(Abstract1 a1) {
    }

    public <T extends Abstract2> void add(T a2) {
    }

    private void method() {
    }

    public abstract class Abstract1 {
        abstract void method1();
    }
    public abstract class Abstract2 {
        abstract boolean isMethod2();
        abstract void setMethod2(boolean required);
    }

}
```

The only difference here is the use of abstract classes instead of interfaces. If you were to call `MyTest#add`, there would be no ambiguity since no object could be an instance of both `Abstract1` and `Abstract2`, since no class can extend multiple classes. For this reason, the Java SE language specifications allows this to be compiled.