# jooq's contain clause with named params

Tags: java, jooq

I am using jooq as an SQL generation engine, and then executing those queries using jdbi.
To map queries to their arguments, I need to explicitly bind it in jdbi, but when i add a named param to contains clause, the param name gets lost.

This test case shows what i expect from getParams() call

```
@Test
public void testJooqContains() {
    DSLContext context = new DefaultDSLContext(SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    Param<String> param = param("P1", "test");
    Condition condition = field("Field1").contains(param);
    SelectQuery<Record> select = context.selectQuery();
    select.addSelect(field("Col1"));
    select.addConditions(Collections.singletonList(condition));
    select.addFrom(table("Table1").as("T1"));

    assertTrue(select.getParams().containsKey("p1"));
}
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem, but your `containsKey()` call should use `P1`, not `p1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in jOOQ's ([#6223](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6223), fixed for 3.10, 3.9.3, 3.8.8) caused by a subtlety in the Java language specification ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799)).

Your `field("Field1").contains(param)` call is linked by the compiler to [`Field.contains(T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#contains-T-) instead of the expected [`Field.contains(Field<T>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#contains-org.jooq.Field-). This happens because your `field("Field1")` expression is of type `Field<Object>`, meaning that both methods are applicable.

A workaround for this problem would be to write:

```
Condition condition = field("Field1", String.class).contains(param);
```