# How to avoid quotes around values in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, postgis, jooq

I am using jOOQ as a SQL builder and I try to build a simple update statement as the following:

```java
DSL.using(SQLDialect.POSTGRES_9_5)
.update(table("Location"))
.set(field("speed"), 50)
.set(field("location"), "ST_PointFromText('POINT(-73 40)', 4326)")
.where(field("id").equal(1))
.getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

As you can see, I am using Postgres and PostGIS, so I need to insert the location using the PostGIS method **ST_PointFromText()**.

The generated SQL looks like this, and fails because the **ST_PointFromText()** is wrapped around single quotes:

```sql
update Location
set speed = 50, location = 'ST_PointFromText(''POINT(-73 40)'', 4326)' 
where id = 1
```

The query should be:

```sql
update Location
set speed = 50, location = ST_PointFromText('POINT(-73 40)', 4326)
where id = 1
```

Is there any way to remove the quotes around the **ST_PointFromText()**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write something like this in jOOQ:

```
.set(field("location"), "ST_PointFromText('POINT(-73 40)', 4326)")
```

Then, the value put on the right side will be considered a bind value. In case you generate the SQL with bind values being inlined, it turns into an escaped string literal. In general, you will *want that*, because it is the correct and expected behaviour given that you're passing a value to the statement (imagine otherwise, the risk of SQL injection, etc.)

If you do want to add some "plain SQL" string to your query, just use [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-), e.g.

```
.set(field("location", String.class), 
     field("ST_PointFromText('POINT(-73 40)', 4326)", String.class))
```

[Note that the data types are required because of this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799). I've just put `String.class` as a dummy type. You should probably implement an actual [converter / binding](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) for your `POINT` data type to be clean.

For more information about plain SQL and plain SQL templating, see these sections of the manual:

- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/
- https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/