# kotlin overload resolution ambiguity when generic type is bound to Any

Tags: kotlin, generics, overload-resolution

Consider [this code](https://pl.kotl.in/gGgevtk-e):

```kotlin
fun main() {
    class A<T> {
        fun m(t: T): Unit {
            print("T")
        }
        fun m(t: List<T>): Unit {
            print("List<T>")
        }
    }
    
    val a: A<Any> = A()
    val l: List<Any> = listOf()
    a.m(l)
}
```

The `a.m(l)` call seems to be ambiguous with the following error:

> Overload resolution ambiguity: public final fun m(t: Any): Unit defined in main.A public final fun m(t: List<Any>): Unit defined in main.A

My intuition tells me that the `m(t: List<T>)` overload should be more specific, but my intuition was already wrong once in the past, [when I had a similar case in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799).

I can call the "wrong" overload like this:

```java
a.m(l as Any)
```

But how can I explicitly call the desired `m(t: List<T>)` overload? Casting `a.m(l as List<Any>)` doesn't work.

Comment: Avoid using `Any` ang go for ( a new ) interface, which can be anything - just dont use the class Any

Comment: @Neo: This question is specifically about `Any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An auxiliary function can help:

```kotlin
fun <T> A<T>.mList(l: List<T>) {
    this.m(l);
}
a.mList(l)
```

Still curious about an alternative that doesn't involve any indirection like this