# How to create 'update' using multiple 'set' methods

Tags: java, sql-update, jooq

**Synopsis:** I'm trying to create an SQL update using jOOQ

```
DSL.using(connection)
.update(DSL.table("dogs"))
.set(DSL.field("age"), DSL.field("age").add(1))
.set(DSL.field("rabies"), "true")
.where(DSL.field("id").eq("Kujo"))
.execute();
```

**Issue:**

> The method set(Field<Object>, Object) is ambiguous for the type UpdateSetFirstStep<Record>

**Question:** How do I create this update using jOOQ?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Don't forget to show us your current SQL attempt.

Comment: @jarlh: What's not minimal or reproducible about this example?

Comment: No sample data, no expected result. No SQL.

Comment: @jarlh: Everything needed to answer the question is there. There is no need for sample data, or expected results, or SQL when the problem is related to jOOQ and why the Java compiler cannot compile a jOOQ query.

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag, since this doesn't seem to need any SQL assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ran into this problem: [Reference is ambiguous with generics](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799)

#### Fixing your query

It's always a good idea to attach data types with your jOOQ expressions. In your particular case, you can work around the problem by specifying things like:

```java
DSL.field("age", SQLDataType.INTEGER)
```

Or, shorter, with the usual static imports:

```java
field("age", INTEGER)
```

#### Using the code generator

However, jOOQ is best used with its [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/), [see also this article here](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). Not only will you avoid problems like these, but you also get compile time type safety (of data types and meta data), advanced features like [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/) and much more.

Your query would then look like this:

```java
DSL.using(connection)
   .update(DOGS)
   .set(DOGS.AGE, DOGS.AGE.add(1))
   .set(DOGS.RABIES, true)
   .where(DOGS.ID.eq("Kujo"))
   .execute();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for your help Lukas. This was very informative

Comment: @stackoverflow: For more infos about why you should use the code generator, see also [this article that I've written now](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/), as these problems are very frequent among users of jOOQ without code generation

Comment: Thanks Lukas, this has been most helpful!