# How to convert any type of Java object with JSON/JSONB column in PostgreSQL using JOOQ on a generic way?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jooq

I'm asking how can I write a generic solution for inserting and selecting any type of Java objects to and from a `JSON` or `JSONB` PostgreSQL database column.
Additionally I have to use (inject) my Jackson `ObjectMapper`, because it's a pre-configured Spring bean.
I tried to solve it with a custom `ConverterProvider` and it's working fine on the select side, but my converter provider isn't called when I did the insert. Did I miss something?

I checked the jOOQ documentation and some stack overflow article about the `Biding` solution, but I don't want to exactly specify the `userType`. So I cannot register the `Binding`, because I cannot declare the exact `userType`.

**My goal is that:**
I would like to eliminate the requirements for the Java object string serialization in the repository classes for every `JSON` and `JSONB` field (and the requirements to inject my `ObjectMapper` into every repository). I don't want to write this code line for each `JSONB` field, jOOQ should do it under the hood with my `JSONConverterProvider`.

```
.set(myJSONBTableField, JSONB.jsonb(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myJavaObjectToStore))
```

I would like to use simply that:

```
.set(myJSONBTableField, myJavaObjectToStore)
```

I would like to ask jOOQ to store any type of Java object with the help of my custom `ObjectMapper` bean, if the DB column type is `JSON` or `JSONB`. My `JSONBConverterProvider` is called in the read phase, but not in the write phase. The `JSONBConverterProvider` has a converter for the vica conversion too, but jOOQ doesn't use it.

The relevant part of my jOOQ configuration:

```
@Bean
public DefaultConfigurationCustomizer ziffitJooqCustomizer(JSONConverterProvider converterProvider) {
        return configuration -> configuration
            .set(converterProvider)
            .settings()...
```

My custom converter provider:

```
@ConditionalOnClass(DSLContext.class)
@Component
public class JSONConverterProvider implements ConverterProvider {

    private final ConverterProvider delegate = new DefaultConverterProvider();
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JSONConverterProvider(ObjectMapper mapper) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public <T, U> Converter<T, U> provide(Class<T> dbClass, Class<U> entityClass) {
        if (dbClass == JSON.class) {
            return getJSONConverter(dbClass, entityClass);
        } else if (dbClass == JSONB.class) {
            return getJSONBConverter(dbClass, entityClass);
        } else {
            // Delegate all other type pairs to jOOQ's default
            return delegate.provide(dbClass, entityClass);
        }
    }

    private <T, U> Converter<T, U> getJSONConverter(Class<T> dbClass, Class<U> entityClass) {
        return Converter.ofNullable(dbClass, entityClass,
            t -> {
                try {
                    return mapper.readValue(((JSON) t).data(), entityClass);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new DataTypeException("JSON deserialization error", e);
                }
            },
            u -> {
                try {
                    return (T) JSON.valueOf(mapper.writeValueAsString(u));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new DataTypeException("JSON serialization error", e);
                }
            }
        );
    }

    private <T, U> Converter<T, U> getJSONBConverter(Class<T> dbClass, Class<U> entityClass) {
        return Converter.ofNullable(dbClass, entityClass,
            t -> {
                try {
                    return mapper.readValue(((JSONB) t).data(), entityClass);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new DataTypeException("JSONB deserialization error", e);
                }
            },
            u -> {
                try {
                    return (T) JSONB.valueOf(mapper.writeValueAsString(u));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new DataTypeException("JSONB serialization error", e);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using the read query like this:

```
dslCtx
  .select(myJSONBTableField)
  .from(myTable)
  .where(...)
  .fetchOptionalInto(myClazz);
```

And this is working fine, and call my `JSONBConverterProvider`.

But my write query doesn't.
I would like to use the write query like this:

```
dslCtx
  .insertInto(myTable)
  .set(myJSONBTableField, myJavaObjectToStore)
  .execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why doesn't the `ConverterProvider` work for you

The `ConverterProvider` SPI (along with the `RecordMapperProvider` and `RecordUnmapperProvider` SPIs) overrides the behaviour of all reflection based auto-data type conversion capabilities on a per-column / member match basis, which mostly affects the [`Record::from`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#from(java.lang.Object)) and [`Record::into`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#into(java.lang.Class)) methods, and related methods on other types.

Notice that if you project your field without passing a class literal, you would get a `Record1<JSONB>` record, and you wouldn't expect that to use your `JSONBConverterProvider`. As such, it doesn't affect any of the otherwise type safe methods, such as `set()` from `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, nor `select(...).fetch()`.

#### What does work for you?

Instead, do attach a `Converter<JSONB, Object>` or better ([to avoid problems like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361513/521799)), a `Converter<JSONB, MyMarkerInterface>` converter to all of your JSONB columns, which should be mapped using your generic JSON conversion logic. I think the problem you had is that you didn't want to attach any *specific* Java class to your JSONB columns, as the concrete class can depend on the JSONB content. But you don't have to! jOOQ doesn't care what the `U` type in your `Converter<T, U>` is. It is only used for type safety, so any `MyMarkerInterface` type is fine.

With that approach, you can still use the `fetchOptionalInto(myClazz)` call, which will just implement an unsafe downcast from `MyMarkerInterface` to `MyClazz`

Comment: Dear Lukas, thanks for clarifying the situation to me. I didn't know that part: "it doesn't affect any of the otherwise type safe methods". This marker interface is a good idea, it did not come to my mind. It's a little extra effort, but not so much. Thanks.

Comment: Dear Lukas,
I'm using the code generator, but my mapping logic is using an `objectMapper` bean. Is there any way to create the `Converter<JSONB, MyMarkerInterface>` as a bean, and attach it to every JSONB column in the app init phase, like my `JSONBConverterProvider` configuration? Or Do I have to inject the converter into each repository, and add as an ad-hoc converter to each JSONB field?

Comment: You attach it to your generated code: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types. You can't inject it to generated code, though, but that might not be necessary? Perhaps better ask a new question with details?